# Laravel - Undefined variable: vendedor (View: C:\wamp64\www\oficina2.0\oficina2.0\oficina\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, undefined-variable

I'm using Laravel and I get this error  Undefined variable in my view, I send 3 variables to the view and say this one is not deaclared

this is my view

```
@extends('templates.template')
@section('content')

@csrf
<table class="table table-striped table-dark">
<h2 class="text-center font-weight-bold mb-4">Orçamentos</h2>
<br>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <select data-column="0" class="form-control filter-input">
        <option value="">Vendedores</option>
        @foreach($vendedor as $obj)
        <option value="{{$obj}}">{{$obj}}</option>
        @endforeach
     </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Procurar pelo cliente" data-column="8">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="date" class='form-control filter-input' placeholder="Procurar pelo cliente" data-column="2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th  scope="col">Vendedor</span></th>
      <th  scope="col">Cliente</span></th>
      <th  scope="col">Data </span></th>
      <th  scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th   scope="col">
      <a href="{{url('orcamentos/create')}}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mb-2"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Adicionar </button>
      </a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

and this is the controller function where i send the data sorted by the function in the view

```
 public function index()
 {
   $orcamentos = ModelsOrcamentoModel::get();
   $vendedores = ModelsOrcamentoModel::sortBy('vendedor')->pluck('vendedor')->unique();
   $clientes = ModelsOrcamentoModel::sortBy('cliente')->pluck('cliente')->unique();
   $data = ModelsOrcamentoModel::sortBy('created_at');

   return view('index')->with('orcamento',$orcamentos,'vendedor',$vendedores,'cliente',$clientes,'data',$data);
 }
```

Comment: Your method is wrong , try instead `return view('index', compact('orcamento','vendedor','cliente',,'data'));`

Comment: return view('index')->with(array('orcamento' => $orcamento, 'vendedor' => $vendedor, 'cliente' => $clienter, 'data' => $data)); try this also

Comment: Now is giving me another error   `Call to undefined method App\Models\OrcamentoModel::sortBy()`

Answer (score 3):

```
return view('index', [
  'orcamento' => $orcamentos,
  'vendedor'  => $vendedores,
  'cliente'   => $clientes,
  'data'      => $data
]);
```

Comment: Now is giving me another error Call to undefined method App\Models\OrcamentoModel::sortBy()

Comment: Change `ModelsOrcamentoModel::all()->sortBy('vendedor')` instead of `ModelsOrcamentoModel::sortBy('vendedor')`

Answer (score 1):

Pass multiple variables in a controller to view like this,

```
return view('index')->with(array('orcamento' => $orcamento, 'vendedor' => $vendedor, 'cliente' => $clienter, 'data' => $data));
```

or

```
return view('index')->with(compact('orcamento', 'vendedor', 'cliente', 'data'));
```

or

```
return view('index', compact(['orcamento', 'vendedor', 'cliente', 'data']));
```

Comment: Now is giving me another error Call to undefined method App\Models\OrcamentoModel::sortBy()

Comment: sortby used on collection

Comment: ModelsOrcamentoModel::pluck('vendedor')->unique()->sortBy('vendedor');